# Apache Fails To Acknowledge HTTPS Virtual Host

Tags: apache-2.2, virtualhost, https

I am running Apache 2.6 on my computer running Arch Linux. It runs a mail server, and because I wanted to setup webmail, I decided I would create my own SSL certificates, as only my friends and family would be using it. I configured Apache to serve secure data on port 443, but it doesn't seem to work.

My virtual host file:

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerAdmin postmaster@duncan.usr.sh
    DocumentRoot "/srv/http"
    <IfModule mod_ssl>
        SSLEngine on
        SSLCertificateFile /srv/ssl/duncan.crt
        SSLCertificateKeyFile /srv/ssl/duncan.key
        SSLCertificateChainFile /srv/ssl/duncan.crt
    </IfModule>


</VirtualHost>
```

I also made sure to uncomment mod_log_config and mod_ssl in httpd.conf, as well as the line that includes the file that contains all the virtual hosts (I checked the path too). What is going on?

In the error log, I get:

```
[Thu Aug 15 11:03:45.445668 2013] [ssl:warn] [pid 29779:tid 139642496866112] AH01906: RSA server certificate is a CA certificate (BasicConstraints: CA == TRUE !?)
[Thu Aug 15 11:03:45.551540 2013] [ssl:warn] [pid 29782:tid 139642496866112] AH01873: Init: Session Cache is not configured [hint: SSLSessionCache]
[Thu Aug 15 11:03:45.551839 2013] [ssl:warn] [pid 29782:tid 139642496866112] AH01906: RSA server certificate is a CA certificate (BasicConstraints: CA == TRUE !?)
[Thu Aug 15 11:03:45.551903 2013] [lbmethod_heartbeat:notice] [pid 29782:tid 139642496866112] AH02282: No slotmem from mod_heartmonitor
[Thu Aug 15 11:03:45.553665 2013] [mpm_event:notice] [pid 29782:tid 139642496866112] AH00489: Apache/2.4.6 (Unix) OpenSSL/1.0.1e configured -- resuming normal operations
```

I used the following command to generate the certificates:

```
openssl req -x509 -nodes -days 365 -newkey rsa:2048 -keyout duncan.key -out duncan.crt
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its not clear what "but it doesn't seem to work" means in this instance.

Perhaps Apache is not listening?

Run

```
netstat -tupln
```

To see if apache is listening on port 443, if it is not, then you probably need

```
Listen 443 somewhere in your apache configuration and then restart apache.
```

Comment: That worked. I never thought of that.